# How to use Angular6 in cordaapp

Tags: corda

I want to use Angular 6 in Cordapp which is running at port 4200 and is placed under `Java-Source/Src/main/Resouces` directly.

Every node web app is running at `http://localhost:10009/web/example/` and `http://localhost:10011/web/example/`.

How can I configure the node settings? I want to use Angular 6 inCordapp-Example given in docs. How can I do that? What node configuration changes need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Angular 6 would not have to be placed on the node. You would import it using a `script` directive in your HTML front-end.

You can see an example of doing this for Angular 1.6 here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/resources/exampleWeb/index.html#L28.